# Work with Files and DocumentLibraries with Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I'm struggling to find how Sharepoint works.

My goal is to upload a file to the 'Document Center' of my company from php using the Graph.

I think DocumentLibraries are seen as drives but I can't find the name or ID of the Document folder.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mycompany.sharepoint.com/drive/{ID TO FIND}/children

How can I find this ID ? (and if you know how i can find childrens IDs, it could be interesting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can get the libraries data:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{hostName}:/{optionalSubsiteUrl}:/drives
```

example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/yoursite.sharepoint.com:/sites/testsite:/drives
```

You will get list of all drives with theirs' id (Property called **id**). Next you can access drive items like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/root/children
```

Hope it will help:)

Comment: THANKS ! (I forgot the "/sites" between the host and the site when i tried server-relative path)

Comment: With Java API getting a site with path this works : `msGraphClient.sites("MyDomain.sharepoint.com:/sites/MySite:")` Don't forget `:` for domain AND site. Working with V1.0 Graph API.